# Why is my Python program is not printing to the nohup log file when I am using carriage returns?

Tags: python-3.x, printing, carriage-return, nohup

I'm writing my program in Python3, and have most of my print statements begin with carriage returns. When I tail the nohup log file I never anything get logged.
Why don't these prints get logged? And how do I fix this while keeping my return carriages?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this was an issue with the carriage returns themselves. But rather the fact that my output was not getting flushed. So setting flush to true fixed it:

```
print('...', flush = True)
```